# Tabular SSAS Analyze in Excel error

Tags: excel, ssas, tabular

I've created a new Tabular Project with SSDT2015 and deployed it on a SSAS2012 named instance, from Management Studio I'm able to connect to the SSAS database and with an EVALUATE command I can see the rows of deployed tables.
If I press Analyze in Excel from SSDT appears a window Analysis Services Connector 13 asking me to choose between Analysis Server and Cube file.

I've tried both options but clicking on finish I can see a grayed out Excel sheet with no connection available.

If I try to connect to SSAS from a fresh Excel using From Analysis Service option, filling the required info leads me to the following message "No data fields are available in the OLAP Cube". Can someone suggest me a way to solve this issue ? Best regards Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding a Measure to a table in my cube, something like AVERAGE('Table'[Field]) or SUM('AnotherTable'[AnotherField]) over a number of rows. After I added this I was able to load my cube in Excel as a pivot table.